# How do I add LinkedIn login to Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, linkedin-api, meteor-accounts

I have tried both pauli:accounts-linkedin and jonperl:linkedin packages in combination with accounts-base & accounts-oauth. I tried it with and without accounts-ui. My Facebook login button is working seemlessly. The error I now get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.loginWithLinkedin is not a function
```

Once this works, I would also like to customize the permissions granted. If you have any hints on what could be wrong/what I could have forgotten, that'd be great. Otherwise, if you are aware of any example projects or docs, that would be nice, because I could not find any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I made it eventually work is with the [pauli:accounts-linkedin](https://atmospherejs.com/pauli/accounts-linkedin) package. [Accounts-UI](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui) package doesn't work, so just build your own login button:

in html:

```
<button id="loginBtn">Login with LinkedIn</button>
```

in javascript:

```
Template.loginTemplate.events({
  'click #loginBtn':function(){
    Meteor.loginWithLinkedIn({
      requestPermissions: ['r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress']
      }, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log('error with login is: ', err);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

the permissions are to be found on the [developer page](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/) of linkedin. Last step now is to add the following document to the meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "J2LPm7ocGfzuiK9J2", 
    "service" : "linkedin", 
    "clientId" : [clientID from linkedin developer page], 
    "secret" : [secret from linkedin developer page]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with third party login without the Mdg support, you cannot know which one will work, test more packages an can asure you that one will work

https://atmospherejs.com/?q=linkedin

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.loginWithLinkedin is not a function make sure you have all the dependencies installed

Comment: how do I ensure that all dependencies are installed?