# LinkedIn integration in Meteor using pauli accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate signIn using LinkedIn in my meteor application.

I have the following packages installed:

```
pauli:accounts-linkedin
pauli:linkedin-config-ui
accounts-password@1.5.1
useraccounts:bootstrap
```

I am using `{{>atForm}}` to show:

```
1. SignIn using LinkedIn (not working, nothing happens when I click on it)
2. Signup and SignIn using username and password (working well)
```

[Here is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYV2B.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
Template.login.events
    "click #linkedin": () ->
        Meteor.loginWithLinkedin () ->
            sAlert.error err
```

I have the following questions:

```
1. How to request permissions from LinkedIn ?
2. Any other information needed to make signin using LinkedIn to work
```

Comment: Hello @saikumarb23, sorry to leave you hanging, buddy. While working out on answer to your question, I stumbled upon this question which pretty much does the whole thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238586/how-do-i-add-linkedin-login-to-meteor?rq=1

Comment: I tried that link before posting this question, it didn't work for me.

Comment: I see. Did you add meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration to the collection as mentioned? Also, would you kindly share your .version file? So, I can compare it with mine.